# Javascript array weirdness : ar[0] * ar[0] != ar[0] ^ 2

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just came across an issue that I can't quite explain:

```
> num = [1,2,3,4,5]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
> num[0]
1
> num[0] ^ 2
3
> num[0] * num[0]
1
```

What is going on here?? what if I needed to take my array number to a larger power this would get quite verbose. Why won't the `^` work?? obviously `1^2 != 3`

Thanks for any help

Comment: That's not what the `^` does. You need to use `Math.pow(num[0], 2)`

Comment: That's a bitwise XOR, not an exponent operator.

Comment: [Bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Comment: In base 2, decimal 1 = 001 and decimal 2 = 010.  So 1^2 = 001 XOR 010 = 011 = decimal 3

Comment: Thanks for the clarification . I was looking for the Math.pow function ... Thanks for entertaining my noob question.